# Time Series Analysis, ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, spss, arima

I'm currently performing a time series analysis using the ARIMA model. I cannot read the PACF and ACF graphs in order to determine P & Q values. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

[image: PACF]

Answer (score 0):

Autocorrelation shows the correlation of past observations (lags) with the time series, which is the correlation of the time series with itself. If you have a time series y(t), then you calculate the correlation of `y(t)` and `y(t-1)`, `y(t)` and `y(t-2)`, and so on.

The problem with the autocorrelation is that so called intermediary effects/indirect correlations are also included. If `y(t)` and `y(t-1)` correlate, and `y(t-1)` and `y(t-2)` also correlate. This influences the correlation of `y(t)` and `y(t-2)` indirectly. You can find a more detailed explanation here:

https://otexts.com/fpp2/non-seasonal-arima.html

Partial autocorrelation also shows the correlation of a time series and it’s lags, but intermediary effects are removed. That means in the PACF you can only see how `y(t)` is influenced directly by `y(t-1)`, `y(t-2)`, and so on. Maybe also have a look here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-from-scratch-autocorrelation-and-partial-autocorrelation-explained-1dd641e3076f

Now, how do you read ACF and PACF plots? The plot shows you the correlation per each lag. A correlation coefficient usually ranges from -1 meaning a perfect negative relationship to +1 meaning a perfect positive relationship. 0 means no relationship at all. In your case, `y(t)` and `y(t-1)` -> lag 1 correlate with a coefficient of around -0.55, meaning a medium strong negative relationship. `y(t)` and `y(t-8)` -> lag 8 correlate with a coefficient of +0.3, meaning a weak positive relationship. The confidence limit shows you whether the correlation is statistically significant. Basically, this means that every bar that crosses the line is a “true” correlation that is not random or so, you can use these correlations. On the other hand, `t(y)` and `t(y-2)` -> lag 2 have a very weak correlation that seems to be more or less random. You cannot use this relationship.

In general, strong correlations in the PACF indicate the usage of an MA model, so you should use and ARIMA(0, d, q) model. I would recommend to use the first, third and fourth lag, maybe also fifth lag, since these have at least medium strong, significant correlations. This means an ARIMA(0, d, [1, 3, 4, 5]) model.

But you also need the ACF plot to find the best ARIMA order, especially the p value.

Answer (score 0):

First perform one differentiaiton, and then read number of lags for PACF, for current plot P is 8, which is quite high

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).